# https/ssl causing issues when sending HTML over curl

Tags: php, curl, https, wkhtmltopdf

I have a curl script on a website that makes a post request to a server using CURL. On the other end I use wkhtmltopdf to generate a PDF with the HTML received, this works fine when https is not enabled on the website, however as soon as I enable https the PDF genetation throws errors.

MY curl script

```
$url = Yii::app()->params['pdfUrl']; //Equals http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/server/?r=pdf/generatePdf

            $body = array(
                "client_url"=>Yii::app()->params['pdfClientURL'],
                "client_id"=>Yii::app()->params['pdfClientID'],
                "title"=>urlencode($title),
                "content"=>urlencode(($content))

            );
            foreach($body as $key=>$value) { $body_str .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
                rtrim($body_str,'&');

            curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body_str);

            curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $pdf = curl_exec ($c);

            curl_close ($c);
            header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
            header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
            header("Accept-Ranges: none");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".str_replace(' ', '_', $title).".pdf");
            echo $pdf;
            Yii::app()->end();
```

What could this be that https is causing?

ERRORS I get on WKHTML2PDF

```
WKPDF system error: <pre>Loading pages (1/6)
[> ] 0%
[======> ] 10%
[===========> ] 19%
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
[============================================================] 100%
Counting pages (2/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Resolving links (4/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
[> ] Preparing
[============================================================] Page 1 of 1
Done
</pre>
```

Comment: Looks like wkhtml2pdf is having trouble performing under ssl, but I'm not sure why it is doing ANYTHING in ssl. My first guess is that since you are requesting with https, wkhtml2pdf is trying to fetch images using ssl as well. I haven't used wkhtml2pdf under ssl before - can you turn that off manually, or maybe explicitly load the images with http, or even locally? Another approach is to fix the actual problem and figure out why wkhtml2pdf is failing with its SSL - did you compile it yourself?

Comment: @Keeyai - No did not compile it myself

Comment: @Keeyai - It's indeed the images, I tried without any images in the PDF and then it works. So I need to find a way to do this. I'm using htaccess to force to use ssl. Maybe I need to exclude images in the .htaccess

Comment: Found the solution @Keeyai - Installed openssl-devel - Check out the url http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=17&q=ssl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, found the problem after @Keeyai pointed me into the right direction. I managed to find this post, http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=17&q=ssl and installed openssl-devel  on the server where wkhtml2pdf is installed and problem solved. Since the problem was caused by images using a https link

yum install openssl-devel did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the curl_setopts page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Things like CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false might help.

Have a look through that page at the various options relating to ssl - sure you will find your answers there...